# Twilio Chat Message consumption horizon and read status for android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, chat, twilio

The [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/consumption-horizon) doesn't seem to mention a way to do this in Android/iOS ? I don't see any undocumented methods to set the consumption horizon.

Comment: You are right and the documentation should mention that. I will follow this up.

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The methods to do this in iOS are on the `TCHMessages` class. You can either [`setLastConsumedMessageIndex`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/chat/releases/0.16.1/docs/Classes/TCHMessages.html#//api/name/setLastConsumedMessageIndex:) or [`advanceLastConsumedMessageIndex`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/chat/releases/0.16.1/docs/Classes/TCHMessages.html#//api/name/advanceLastConsumedMessageIndex:).

The methods you want in Android are on the `Messages` class. You can either [`setLastConsumedMessageIndex`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/0.11.2/docs/com/twilio/chat/Messages.html#setLastConsumedMessageIndex-long-) or [`advanceLastConsumedMessageIndex`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/0.11.2/docs/com/twilio/chat/Messages.html#advanceLastConsumedMessageIndex-long-).

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I need help for iOS Twilio chat can we do chat when you are available.

Comment: I am on holiday right now, but check out [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat) to start with. Then, if you’re stuck you can try getting in contact with [Twilio support](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) to discuss your issue. Or if you can wait until next week, drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will check and if I need any help, I will buzz you. :) thanks.....